Current term in Maxwell's fourth law redundant?
Maxwell's fourth law states:
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \mathbf{J} + \mu_0 \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}.
$$
My question is why is it the case that the $J$ term is not redundant? We know that a moving charge produces an electric field that changes around the charge because of its movement. And this changing electric field causes a changing magnetic field in other words the curl of $E$ exists. But isn't current just a bunch of moving charge so that means that a wire carrying a current would produce an electric field around it that expands radially and can be calculated by the sum of all the electric fields of each charge. The resulting magnetic field would be the sum of all the curls of the electric fields produced by each charge. And this comes from Maxwell's third law.


How is what ChatGPT says relevant to the question? 2. Why would the term be "redundant"? I don't really understand the supposed argument here - clearly the solutions to the equation with the term are different from the solutions without the $\mu_0 J$ term, no? The world we observe obeys the version of the equation with that term. What exactly is the question about that?


I deleted the ChatGPT stuff and the second question

Take the divergence, then use Gauss's law. As long as you don't throw away the current term, you get the continuity equation, i.e. charge conservation.

How would you explain magnetostatics without that term?

I do not know why all of you are getting so mad. What I am asking is why wouldn't the magnetic field of the current simply be the result of summing the curl of the electric field of each charge and adding it together to calculate the magnetic field outside of the wire? When one does that it apparently gives 0 for magnetic field. So you need the current term. I do not understand why curl E would work for a single charge moving through a wire when calculating the magnetic field but now all of the sudden if you have more charges this won't work and you need to include a second current term?

Besides one charge moving through space is also current and I am not certain if we would be including the current term to calculate the magnetic field around it but simply dE/dt

The current term is not redundant. Consider an uncharged DC current carrying wire. For every part of the wire there is charge entering and charge leaving. Those two produce a $dE/dt$ that cancel each other. So the net is $0$.
Since we observe a nonzero magnetic field and since the second term is zero, there must be another independent term. That is the term with the current.

What about if we observe a point outside of the wire? If we have one charge moving along a wire it's electric field will change with time and so we can therefore calculate the magnetic field. What makes a bunch of charges moving together any more special that now all the sudden we need to include the current term because summing the changing electric field outside of all of these charges gives 0?

@LEXORAI At a point outside of the wire there are no charges, so obviously no $dE/dt$ is produced there either. There is nothing "all the sudden" needing to include the current term. You need to include the current term for a single charge also. It just becomes obvious for a wire carrying a steady current.

So a single charge produces a magnetic field from its changing electric field + the small current from this single charge?

Why doesnt a changing magnetic field theb also produce a current analogously in 3d maxwell law?

Think of the implications of that. Magnetic fields can change in pure vacuum. So if a changing magnetic field produced a current then you would have currents in pure vacuum, even at low energy. Do we observe that happening?

Ok. But can you confirm that if i want to calculate the magnetic field of a charge i need to then consider it as a current and the changing electric field around it?

@LEXORAI yes. See here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential It is derived from the full Maxwell’s equations, including both terms of Amperes law

It's quite elementary: the continuity equation for the current density $$:
$$∇· + \frac{∂ρ}{∂t} = 0,$$
and the field equation for the charge density $ρ$:
$$∇· = ρ.$$
The current density $$ gives you the next flow across any cross-sectional area associated with the volume charge density $ρ$, via the continuity equation, which you definitely want; while the field law for the charge density $ρ$ is the very essence of Coulomb's Law, so you want that too. In free space, the electric displacement $$ is related to the electric field $$ by $ = ε₀$.
From this, it follows:
$$∇·\frac{∂}{∂t} = \frac{∂(∇·)}{∂t} = \frac{∂ρ}{∂t} = -∇·.$$
Thus
$$∇·\left(\frac{∂}{∂t} + \right) = ,$$
thus showing that the total current
$$ = \frac{∂}{∂t} + ,$$
as Maxwell called it, is solenoidal, and is therefore expressible as the curl
$$ = ∇×$$
of the field magnetic field $$ that is historically connected to Ampère's Circuital Law and The Amperian Loop Model for magnetic dipoles. In free space (as opposed to magnetized materials) this, in turn, is connected to the magnetic induction $$, that currents experience the feel of, by $ = μ₀$. In his earliest writings, in the pre-treatise days, Maxwell literally identified the two and (when rendered in contemporary terms) wrote $$ as the diglyph $μ$. The qualifier is because his $$ has a divisor $4π$ in it, compared to ours and his $μ$ has a factor $4π$ in it compared to ours.
So, you can add Ampere's law as the third reason, as it clinches the argument of tying the magnetic field to the field $$ that the solenoidal field $$ is the curl of.
The thing you forgot about is capacitance! The $$ current doesn't flow across a capacitor, but the $$ current does, since the charge $ρ$ builds up (or down) when the current $$ flows into (or out of) it, so that all of $$ is coming from the time rate of change of the field $$ that is associated with the charge (again: my reasons number one and two); while in a conductor, the only current contributing to $$ is the convection $$. In the conductor, the net charge is not changing, but just flowing along, so there's no contribution to $$ by any time rate of change of the associated field $$.
